# Why block div not get height auto?

Tags: css, css-float

Code:

```
<div class="RightAsideBlock">
    <div class="BlockHeader">TEST HEADER</div>
    <div class="BlockContent ForTags">
        <div class="PopularTags"><a href="" >test</a></div>
        <div class="PopularTags"><a href="" >test</a></div>
        <div class="PopularTags"><a href="" >test</a></div>
        <div class="PopularTags"><a href="" >test</a></div>
        <div class="PopularTags"><a href="" >test</a></div>
        <div class="PopularTags"><a href="" >test</a></div>
        <div class="PopularTags"><a href="" >test</a></div>
        <div class="PopularTags"><a href="" >test</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.RightAsideBlock {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0.2em 0.2em 2px rgba(122,122,122,0.5);
}

.PopularTags {
    color: #acacac;
    background-color: #ededed;
    border: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #acacac;
    padding: 4px 5px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

In result we have:

[image]

Tell me please why `div.ForTags` not get height auto and divs `div.PopularTags` move beyond the block boundary `div.ForTags` ?

And how make right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following rule

```
.ForTags { overflow: auto }
```

to create a block formatting context for the parent block that contains the floating elements.

Answer (score 0):

The `PopularTags` are floated which means they do not count as content for the containing element when calculating it's height.  You will need to add an element after the floated elements with a style of `clear: both;`  which will fix it.

Additional HTML after the last `PopularTags` element

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Additional CSS

```
.clearfix { clear: both; }
```

More information about clearing floats and other solutions can be found here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html